# Not able to get all tags/text scraping a website using Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The project I am having problems with relates to scraping a website (www.iasg.com) using Python, and the package "Beautifulsoup". I am a beginner to Python, though I have coded previously on an expert level in MATLAB (if that counts).

I am not sure if my current issue is due to:
1. Me not being logged in properly to the site I am trying to scape or
2. The site is badly coded, so that Beautifulsoup cannot scape all tags

What has happened: I tried using the code below to scape all text in the `TD` tags in [link](http://www.iasg.com/groups/group/redleaf-capital-llc2/program/fallback-fundamentals-accounts-50k)

When looking at what Beautifulsoup scraped, it is apparent that it does not include all tags; either due to it not being logged in properly or the tags are simply not there.

```
import mechanize
import html5lib
import cookielib
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def get_fund_links(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    odd = []
    for item in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'small'}):
        odd.append(item["href"])

       fund_links = odd

    return fund_links

def get_fund(fund_url):
     html = urlopen(fund_url).read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
     program = []
     for item in soup.findAll('tr'):
         cols = item.findAll('td')
         for td in cols:
             program.append(td.text)

     return program

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'IE')]

br.open('http://www.iasg.com/home/ctl/login?returnurl=%2f')

for f in br.forms():
    print f

br.select_form(nr=0)

user = br.form['dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtUsername'] = 'yyyy'
passw = br.form['dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtPassword'] = 'xxxx

br.submit()


result = get_fund_links('http://www.iasg.com/managed-futures/performance')
print get_fund(result[0])

print len(result[0])
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the source of the page and confirmed that the data you expect to be there is there?  Perhaps download the page first `curl -G <URL>` and then attempt to parse that.  No point in diagnosing bugs in your code and weird behavior in website due to authentication or lazy loading of data through javascript.

Comment: Not sure I follow; I have tested printing the object soup, to look at the source code it obtained. And the data was not there! The data is however in the website's source code.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code with a username/password that I setup. You're not seeing the info you want because it's not staying logged in. I'm not familiar with mechanize, but your code looks overly complicated. Perhaps the requests module would be more simple, it will handle all the cookies for you.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: You are very kind! I will check your link, try to work the login angle and see if it works. I will revert when done.

Comment: I have now read the Requests documentation and edited the code as such:      payload = {'dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtUsername':'user', 'dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtPassword':'pass'}
     log = requests.post(fund_url, data=payload)
     print log.text

    # html = urlopen(fund_url).read()
     html = log.text

     soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

Comment: I still have the issue of not being sure if I am logged in or not

Comment: What about the other information that needs to be sent in the post request? __EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
__VIEWSTATE
__EVENTVALIDATION
dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtUsername
dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtPassword
ScrollTop
__dnnVariable
__ASYNCPOST
RadAJAXControlID

Comment: I must be misunderstanding requests.post, as I was/am under the impression all arguments are there. The documentation does not give further information on what I need to add as arguments other than what I write above.

Comment: Also, status_code does give 200. I think I might be logged in, just that not all text in the website is being retrieved properly, and I do not know why.

Comment: What documentation are you referring too? Which data you need to send in a post request would depend on the website that you are sending it too. Perhaps it would work with just the data you sent, however I typically look at the requests with chrome dev tools to see what is actually being sent via the post request when I log with my browser. I usually start with sending all of the date, and also replicated any info in the headers, etc... then you can strip out things that you don't want to send to see if it breaks the request.

Comment: Odd, I added all the parameters seen via Chrome Dev Tools (Networks, POST), but now I get an error when trying to log in (seen via .content / -status_code).
Documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: Edited payload code: 
payload_comp =  {'__EVENTTARGET':'dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$cmdLogin', '__VIEWSTATE' : 'too long to post here', '__EVENTVALIDATION': '/wEdAAqULKq7iGMKq0govQu7/2VJ+MkU6MJgKEdmaw9fUm2eTfIWxxCfQJAlyxT795NMrVc4eK3CavW0S9USH2Z/1yXwF1qOVstb6vsv6X0XMVRqIDwGlBo0cJLQU0Um6QLZlToajPLr/vnOzHUuW6aTbnNl5Pip2gbxL1YB0Plt5tj4X1fJ82cLYuNHga3Vmj3QvawglYTgmyD61+C5CtBsuVtAq2jNI4mUq3BL55mAdTElktuDJ2M=', 'dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtUsername':user, 'dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtPassword':pass}